# Typescript indexable types with extended interfaces (TS2322)

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript by reimplementing a flowtype prototype of mine. This issue has me a bit stumped.

```
error TS2322: Type '(state: State, action: NumberAppendAction) => State' is not assignable to type 'Reducer'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'NumberAppendAction'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"number/append"'.

32   "number/append": numberReducer
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/network/tmp.ts:13:3
    13   [key: string]: Reducer
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

The offending code:

```
export interface State {
  sequence: number
  items: Array<any>
}

export interface Action {
  type: string
  payload: any
}

export type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State;
export interface HandlerMap {
  [key: string]: Reducer
}

export interface NumberAppendAction extends Action {
  type: "number/append"
  payload: number
}

export const numberReducer = (state: State, action: NumberAppendAction) : State => {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: [
      ...state.items,
      action.payload
    ]
  }
}

export const handlers: HandlerMap = {
  "number/append": numberReducer
}
```

Changing `Reducer` to:

```
export type Reducer = (state: State, action: any) => State;
```

fixes the issue but then the type guarantees about the action parameter are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that `numberReducer` is not a `Reducer`, and for good reason.  A `Reducer` must accept any `Action` as its second parameter, but `numberReducer` only accepts a `NumberAppendAction`.  That's like a person advertising his services as a dog walker but only accepting chihuahuas.  That's false advertising, despite the fact that chihuahuas are dogs.

The issue here is that type safety requires that [function arguments be contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type) and [not covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_argument_type) in the declared type.  Meaning that a `Reducer` can accept *wider* types, not *narrower* types.  TypeScript has enforced this rule via the [`--strictFunctionTypes` flag](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) introduced in TypeScript 2.6.

The question is what to do about it... you *could* start intentionally breaking type safety by using `any` as you've done, or by turning off `--strictFunctionTypes`.  I don't recommend that, but it's an easy way out.

The type-safe way out is more complicated.  Since TypeScript doesn't have support for [existential types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), you can't easily say something like: "a `HandlerMap` is an object type where each property is a reducer for *some* action type `A` and where the key for that property is `A['type']` (the `type` property for that action)".  The closest reasonable alternative is to make types which are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the action type `A`, and hope we can give the compiler enough hints for it to *infer* the particular `A` or set of `A` types when necessary.

Here's one possible implementation, with a lot of inline comments giving a sketch of how it works.

```
// Reducer is now generic in the action type
type Reducer<A extends Action> = (state: State, action: A) => State;

// a HandlerMap is also generic in a union of action types, where each property
// is a reducer for an action type whose "type" is the same as the key "K" of the property
type HandlerMap<A extends Action> = {
  [K in A['type']]: Reducer<Extract<A, { type: K }>>
}

// when inferring a value of type `HM` that we hope to interpret as a HandlerMap<A>         
// for some A, we can make VerifyHandlerMap<HM>.  If HM is a valid HandlerMap, then
// VerifyHandlerMap<HM> evaluates to HM.  If HM is invalid for some property of key K, then
// VerifyHandlerMap<HM> for that key evaluates to the expected reducer type
type VerifyHandlerMap<HM extends HandlerMap<any>> = {
  [K in string & keyof HM]: (HM[K] extends Reducer<infer A> ?
    K extends A['type'] ? HM[K] : Reducer<{ type: K, payload: any }> : never);
}

// Given a valid HandlerMap HM<A>, get the A.  Note that the standard
// conditional type inference "HM extends HandlerMap<infer A> ? A : never" will
// not work here, A is nested too deepliy inside HandlerMap<A>.  So we manually
// break HM into keys and infer each A from each property and then union them
// together
type ActionFromHandlerMap<HM extends HandlerMap<any>> =
  { [K in keyof HM]: HM[K] extends Reducer<infer A> ? A : never }[keyof HM]

// the helper function asHandlerMap() will take a value we hope is a valid HandlerMap<A>
// for some A, verify that it is valid, and return a HandlerMap<A>.  
// If the type is *invalid*, the compiler should warn on the appropriate property.  
const asHandlerMap = <HM extends HandlerMap<any>>(hm: HM & VerifyHandlerMap<HM>):
  HandlerMap<ActionFromHandlerMap<HM>> => hm;
```

And we can test it out:

```
const handlers = asHandlerMap({
  "number/append": numberReducer
}); // no error, handlers is of type HandlerMap<NumberAppendAction>
```

So that works, and `handlers` is inferred to be of type `Handler<NumberAppendAction>` as desired.

Let's introduce a new `Action` to see how we get warnings when we make a mistake:

```
interface Dog {
  breed: string,      
  bark(): void
}

interface DogWalkAction extends Action {
  type: "dog/walk",
  payload: Dog;
}

declare const dogWalkReducer: (state: State, action: DogWalkAction) => State;
```

And we try this:

```
const handlers = asHandlerMap({
  "number/append": numberReducer,
  "dog/Walk": dogWalkReducer // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '"dog/Walk"' is not assignable to type '"dog/walk"'.
});
```

Oops, I made a typo, the "W" in `dog/Walk` should be lowercase.  Let's fix it:

```
const handlers = asHandlerMap({
  "number/append": numberReducer,
  "dog/walk": dogWalkReducer
}); // okay, handlers is of type HandlerMap<NumberAppendAction | DogWalkAction>
```

And that works and everything is type safe.  As I said before: complicated.  There are other possible implementations but I don't know that there's anything both safe and simple.  It's up to you whether or not you prefer type safety or simplicity.  Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your extensive response. I will spend some time digesting this!